# $5^{th}$ power of any integer is of the form $11k$ or $11k +1$ or $11k -1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$5^{th}$ power of any integer is of the form $11k$ or $11k +1$ or $11k -1$.

Let the integer be $x$. If $x$ has a factor $11$ then $x^5$ is of the form $11k$. Now we consider the case where $11 \not\mid x$ .

By Fermat's Theorem we know that $x^{10} \equiv 1(\mod 11)$. Thus $11 \mid x^{10} -1$ i.e. $11 \mid (x^{5} -1)(x^5 +1)$. Since $11$ is prime, $11 \mid (x^{5} -1)$ or $11 \mid (x^{5} +1)$. Thus $x^5$ is of the form $11k +1$ or $11k -1$.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "the logic of proof" as opposed to "the proof"? Your proof is correct. If you ask a more psecific question you will get a more specific answer.

Comment: I assume tone's proof generalizes to "...the $29$th power of any integer is of the form $59k$, or $59k\pm1$", and so on?

Answer (score 2):

Very nice! Straightforward and simple.

Comment: @John: Can you suggest a more verbose way of elaborating the content of "Your solution is elegant and correct!" May be you missed that the question was "Is my proof correct?"

Comment: Yes. My bad, I was not paying enough attention while doing the review. Please accept my sincere apology @TonyK

Comment: @John: It's quite all right. I, too, have found it all too easy to get into autopilot while in the review queue, and (as quid pointed out) you were certainly not the only person to come to your initial conclusion!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative proof (though I find yours nicer):

- $x\equiv 0\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 0^5\equiv11\cdot   0  \equiv 0\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 1\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 1^5\equiv11\cdot   0+1\equiv+1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 2\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 2^5\equiv11\cdot   3-1\equiv-1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 3\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 3^5\equiv11\cdot  22+1\equiv+1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 4\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 4^5\equiv11\cdot  93+1\equiv+1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 5\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 5^5\equiv11\cdot 284+1\equiv+1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 6\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 6^5\equiv11\cdot 707-1\equiv-1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 7\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 7^5\equiv11\cdot1528-1\equiv-1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 8\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 8^5\equiv11\cdot2979-1\equiv-1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv 9\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv 9^5\equiv11\cdot5368+1\equiv+1\pmod{11}$
- $x\equiv10\pmod{11}\implies x^5\equiv10^5\equiv11\cdot9091-1\equiv-1\pmod{11}$